# How to remove<script> coding in popup notification message?

Tags: php, jquery

I am using php language to do my project and I have a problem about how to remove  coding in popup notification message? Because when I add below  coding, it will show the notification pop up message box:

```
 <script>

 $('#branch_id3').change(function(){
    $('#merchant_type').val(0);
 })

 </script>
```

Then the output show me like below picture,it will show me the coding in the message box:

[image: Output]

Hope anyone can guide me how to remove it. Thanks.

Comment: You need to show more of the script. But you can't have HTML inside an `alert()` call.

Comment: If you're using AJAX and returning a message to be alerted, don't put other HTML in it. If you want to return both a message and HTML, return a JSON object with mutliple properties. Then you can do different things in the client with each property.

Comment: @Barmar Can hide the <script>?

Comment: You could use a regular expression, but why not just do it right?

Comment: Please show your code for the pop up. Preferably as a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap, you should use [Model Popup](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) to display your HTML content instead of `alert`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      
      <input type="text" id="branch_id3" /> <input type="text" id="merchant_type" /> 
      
      <script>
         $('#branch_id3').change(function(){
              $('#merchant_type').val(0);
        })
     </script>
 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks your comment. But I use <?php ?> to write in above , then below is the <script> coding. It show me the coding in popup message

Comment: Because the php coding too long, I can't post here.

Comment: It's the same, you just put your HTML content into `modal-body` then toggle it popup instead of `alert`.